# What is the relation between UART and the tty?

Tags: terminal, tty, protocols, uart

When I write programs for my own FPGA, I must select UART to emulate a terminal and for my FPGA design but I don't know exactly what that means.

I believe that UART is a basic serial transmission protocol, isn't it? And is that the protocol between the program and the terminal and therefore I must choose UART from my programming environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UART (Universal Asynchronous Receiver Transmitter) is not a protocol, it's a piece of hardware capable of receiving and transmitting data over a serial interface. I presume you are selecting some design block for your FPGA design implementing an UART.